# can't leave my app

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities. In first I come to the second activity from first so:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondClass.class);
startActivity(i);
```

but special condition require that I restart first activity because I return to it with same way:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            //...

            Intent i = new Intent(this, FirstClass.class);
            startActivity(i);

            super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Because I can't leave first activity:
If I use

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
        return;
    }
```

or

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        finish();
            System.exit(0);

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

It close my application but open second activity.
Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just call finish() after you start a new activity(and only after you start a new activity) and let android do the rest.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondClass.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

It will start the second activity and close the first one. If you press the back key now it will take you to the last open activity ( not necessarily one from your app )

Answer (score 2):

When you go to your second activity then close the first activity like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondClass.class);
startActivity(i);
finish(); // Close your first activity
```

Now when you are in you second activity then you can restart your first activity by this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, FirstClass.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish(); // Close your second activity
}
```

It is as simple as that :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not do that, I mean start and finish activities by back button press by yourself, because of Android platform already provides you a stack of activities, to change behavior of the activities in the stack and instances of them as well you can use AndroidManifest.xml for that [Activity Launch Mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)